# Umbraco: Get "Last Edits" values from content

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco6

In my umbraco project, i require values in the "last Edited" tab, inside C# code.

[image]

How can i get those values?

Please Help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. Here's one way of doing it:

> // Assure the query is done to the root node, in this case I was on the root controller.
>
> var recentUpdatedNodes =
> Model.Content.DescendantsOrSelf().OrderByDescending(x =>
> x.UpdateDate).Take(50);
>
> ```
> foreach (var node in recentUpdatedNodes)
> {
>     @node.Name
>     @node.Url
>     @node.Id
> }
> ```